# shell script expect and spawn commands

Tags: bash, shell, expect

Actually i am writing 2 scripts of

a.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

PASSPHRASE="PASS"
for i in 1 2
do
echo "say hii:"
done
```

another script of 
b.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ./a.sh
sleep 2
for {set x 1} {$x<3} {incr x} {
expect "say hii:"
send "hii\r"
sleep 10
interact
}

executing ./b.sh
```

so for the first time it is sending `say hii: "and we are sending hii"`

```
for the second time it getting struck in say hii:
```

so i would like to send two times means how many time for loop is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a.sh` finishes after writing say hii twice

```
#!/bin/sh

PASSPHRASE="PASS"
for i in 1 2
do
    echo "say hii:"
    IFS= read -r line && echo "$0 read: $line"
done
```

`b.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ./a.sh
sleep 2
for {set x 1} {$x<3} {incr x} {
    expect "say hii:"
    send "hii\r"
    sleep 1
}
interact
```